# Total Derivative of a Max Function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, utility

I'm studying public economics but my question here is purely mathematical in nature. I have a function:

$$
V(1-\tau, R) = \max_zu((1-\tau)z+R,z)
$$

I need to take the total derivative of this, in my notes, I'm told it is equal to

$$
dV=u_c [-zd\tau + dR] + dz[(1-\tau)u_c + u_z]
$$

where $c^i=(1-\tau)z^i+\tau Z(1-\tau)-E$,

and the notation $u_c$ denotes the derivative of u with respect to c.

Is the first bracket the partial derivative with respect to c and the second the partial derivative with respect to z?

Comment: Doesn't your own note `where the notation uc denotes the derivative of u with respect to c` answer your own question `Is the first bracket the partial derivative with respect to c and the second the partial derivative with respect to z`?